# Remove scroll-bar from iframe

Tags: iframe, google-docs

I have a form from Google docs that I embedded in my website I want the students I coach to fill out but the scrollbar is annoying me. Any way to get rid of it?

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1kMdmk_f4jrAWwZi6q3YD63oUQAg2hvdheAQ-pY_2FRY/viewform?embedded=true" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
```

Comment: Mark the answer you found correct please @MissNikki513

Answer (score 15):

use scrolling="no"

```
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1kMdmk_f4jrAWwZi6q3YD63oUQAg2hvdheAQ-pY_2FRY/viewform?embedded=true" width="760" **scrolling="no"** height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
```

Comment: Answers like these make me wonder " Why didn't I think about it ?" Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's the single scroll bar, or the double scroll bar that's annoying you...depending on the form you're embedding, some sections may be larger than others and they'll need to scroll to continue the form.

I'm very noob here, but fixed a naggy double scroll bar issue for a wix site using their html embed tool...

Taking the google form embedding code, I added the "style" sheet at the beginning and changed height and width to "100%" see here:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {margin:0; overflow: hidden;}
iframe {border: none;}
</style>
<iframe src="YOUR SOURCE" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found if you change the height of your form to say 2000 your form fits on your website without the scroll

e.g. width="650" height="2000"

Answer (score 0):

You can try css: `overflow-y: hidden;`